# How to restrict access for my users to a specific IP?

Tags: node.js, authentication

I am going to build a admin panel which will be accessible only from company's IP address. I never done this before so I don;t really know how this work. Can I just get the IP of the user and match with the IP I've specified and if it matches to let him log in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick google search I found this:

You can get the connected client's IP with this for example:

```js
var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

then just compare the variable with the IP address which you want to have access.

Comment: I just had a look over it and seem to be exactly what I need. Thanks